# How to prevent the execution of php, even if the file is not found?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

There is a lot of requests to that url `/static/tiles/z/x/y.png`.

Now, if file was not found, `index.php` handles the request.

But i want to if the request matches `/static/tiles/.*` and there is no such file, apache is just stop execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following condition to your .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/tiles/.*
```

This will prevent your rule to be met when the requested uri starts with `/static/tiles`.